# How to mock imported function in a Flask Blueprint

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, mocking

I have a Flask Blueprint that imports a function from the parent Flask module as such:
from app_name.utils import try_ad_connection

I am trying to mock/patch `try_ad_connection` but I don't know what my target should be in the patch decorator as the Blueprint is not a module, so targeting `app_name.blueprint_name.try_ad_connection` does not seem to work.

If I change my import to the whole utils file and call `try_ad_connection` by `app_name.utils.try_ad_connection`, I can patch it by using `app_name.utils.try_ad_connection` as the target, but I'd like to avoid importing the whole file to just use one function.

Comment: This requires more content to be able to act on it. I fixed the markup, but I still think it should be closed without code examples.